# How to convert following curl code to ruby code with restclient

Tags: ruby, curl

```
curl http://192.168.253.7:8080/Example-1/restful/data/bulkUpload -H "API_KEY: se5ed3635ee24bb89dd72f" -H "TOKEN:1221231233" -F file=~/Desktop/Sample Import.xlsx
```

And it works fine through terminal.

I have above curl code and converted it to ruby code as follows:

```
require 'rest-client'
RestClient.post(url,
                  :file => File.new(file_path),
                  headers: {'API_KEY' => Settings.API_KEY, 'TOKEN' => Settings.TOKEN})
```

But still i am getting `API _KEY` is not in header response?

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have to specify the headers before the payload. And the `API_KEY` and `TOKEN` should be inside the headers section.
So following RestClient request is the solution for my question.

```
  request = RestClient::Request.new(
      :method => :post,
      :url => url,
      :headers => {'API_KEY' => Settings.API_KEY,'TOKEN' => '123123123'},
      :payload => {
          :multipart => true,
          :file => File.new(file_path, 'rb')
      })
  response = request.execute
```